# AT commands not working on arduino uno with A7 gsm gprs module

Tags: arduino-uno

After all connections have been made, I tried to verify my sketch to the arduino

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// RX, TX
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);

void setup() 
{   
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600); 

  while (mySerial.available())   
  {
    mySerial.read(); 
  }
}

void loop() 
{  
  if (Serial.available())  
  {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read()); 
  }

  if (mySerial.available()) 
  {   
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());  
  }
}
```

After uploading this code to arduino, I tried to confirm.

But it was constantly displaying
¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿
If I set the baud to 9600

But if I set it to 115200, I will not get anything
..
Please help me.

I will be defending my project tomorrow and I am stock here...

Comment: You start your project one day before you have to present it. That's funny ;-)) .... OK, now seriously: In order to get quick help, you should add all information you have, and provide links to the used boards and modules. Your could at least format your code example. Have you seen it, how could someone read it? I've done that for you. "But if I set it to 115200, I will not get anything .. " Which one have you set to 115200? The hardware serial, the software serial, the serial terminal in the IDE, all of them? How did you wire the board? Show a picture of your setup.

Comment: BTW: Formatting code is easy. Just highlight it and then press the {} button in the menu bar of the online editor.

Comment: Have you tried all the other common baud rates? The module might work on one of them. Do you have dicumentation about your module, that states the baudrate?